# Does caffe computes gradients also for layers with learning rate zero (lr_mult = 0) during the backward pass?

Tags: performance, machine-learning, computer-vision, caffe, gradient-descent

I recently trained a Faster R-CNN model using the D-X-Y C++ implementation (https://github.com/D-X-Y/caffe-faster-rcnn/). In order to save training time, I froze the lower (shared) convolutional layers by setting lr_mult = 0. I compared the iteration times with and without frozen layers and found no significant difference. In Caffe, are gradients still computed for these layers for which lr_mult = 0?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain about it, but AFAIK caffe computes the gradient even when `lr_mult: 0` since the gradients may be needed somewhere else down the way.
Have you tried setting [`propagate_down: false`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L347-L354) to stop gradients from propagating?

From `caffe.proto`:

> ```
>   // Specifies whether to backpropagate to each bottom. If unspecified,
>   // Caffe will automatically infer whether each input needs backpropagation
>   // to compute parameter gradients. If set to true for some inputs,
>   // backpropagation to those inputs is forced; if set false for some inputs,
>   // backpropagation to those inputs is skipped.
> ```